# Continuous, at most countably many-to-one function maps compact perfect sets into compact perfect sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity, compactness

I would like to ask any thought on the following exercise from a Supplement to Rudin’s “Principles of Mathematical Analysis”.

> ”Let us call a function $f : X → Y$ “at most countably many to one” if $\forall y \in Y, f^{-1}(y)$ is at most countable. Suppose f is a continuous, at most countably many-to-one map of metric spaces. Show that for every compact perfect subset E, $f(E)$ is a perfect subset of Y.
> ”

I think I got a proof of the above statement by noticing that $f(E)$ is also compact and therefore closed, then I only need to show that it doesn’t contain any isolated point (which is easy to see by contradiction because $f$ is continuous and E is perfect). However I didn’t use the hypothesis of $f$ being at most countably many-to-one.

Any hint on what I am doing wrong is very much appreciated!

Comment: Every point of $E$ is a point of condensation.  If $f:E\to Y$ is continuous and "countably many to one" can $f(E)$ have an isolated point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second part is wrong. $f(E)$ may well contain isolated points without the additional hypothesis. Consider for example $E = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ and $f \colon E \to \mathbf R$ given by $f|_{[0,1]} = 1$, $f|_{[2,3]} = \mathrm{id}$. Then $f(E) = \{1\} \cup [2,3]$, which has isolated points.

Comment: You are actually right! Any hint on how to implement the additional hypothesis?

Comment: @MatteoMenghini  Here is a hint that might help (not too vague).  Why do you need the additional hypothesis?    Mr Martini's example shows that you could just take any compact perfect set $E$ and map it to a single point.  If $f(E)$ is a single point then it certainly is not perfect.   What is special about compact, nonempty perfect sets then that relates to "countability?"   They must be uncountable!  All of them!  Check the Baire category theorem for why.   A second hint would help too, but I'm sure you will figure it out from here.

Comment: Yeah, in the end I managed; I didn’t use Baire Category Theorem because I didn’t really do it but I used the topological characterisation of continuity. Thanks anyway for the hint!!!